# Many-to-Many mySQL selection

Tags: mysql, sql, select

How can I get a select result showing all the interests of a certain user. My 3 tabels look like this:

Tabel: User 
-- ID 
-- first_name 
-- last_name 
-- etc...

Tabel: Interests 
-- ID 
-- title

Tabel: User_Interests 
-- User_ID
-- Interests_ID

This is what I got so far:

```
SELECT 
    User.ID, User.first_name
FROM
    User
        INNER JOIN
    User_Interests ON User_Interests.User_ID = User.ID
WHERE
    User.ID = 0

    enter code here
```

Comment: And what is the issue with your code?  I mean, it selects only user information, but you seem on the right path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just also join to `Interests` table

Try this:

```
SELECT 
User.ID, User.first_name, Interests.title 
FROM  User
INNER JOIN User_Interests 
ON User_Interests.User_ID = User.ID
INNER JOIN Interests 
ON User_Interests.Interests_ID = Interests.ID 
WHERE
User.ID = 0
```